# String concatenation not working properly in C using sizeof() but it works for strlen()

Tags: c, sizeof, string-concatenation, strlen

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char strp[] = "hello";
    char strq[] = " world";
    strcat(strp,strq);
    puts(strp); //hello world
    printf("%d",sizeof(strp)-1);//this gives 5(length of 'hello' -1 for '\0')
    printf("%d",strlen(strp));//gives correct answer(11)
    return 0;
}
```

Why does sizeof give wrong answer but strlen give right answer in this case?

Answer (score 4):

The `sizeof` operator tells you the size in bytes of the type of its operand.  Since `strp` has type `char [6]` (i.e. just large enough to store its initiazer since you didn't give an explicit size), it's size is 6.  So it's not giving the `wrong` answer, it's just not telling you what you think it is.

There's a larger problem with this code however, namely you're appending to the string contained in `strp` but there's no room for any additional characters.  As a result, you write past the end of the array, triggering [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The destination of `strcat` has to have enough room to store the concatenated string.  In this case, `strp` would have to be at least 12 elements long.

Answer (score 2):

1. `strcat(strp,strq);` invokes undefined bahaviour as `strp` is not large enough to accommodate the concatenated string. The result of this operation cannot be predicted.
2. Never ever use `sizeof` to get string length. `sizeof(x)` is giving you the size of in bytes `x`.

Try the same with `char strp[100] = "hello";`

***ALWAYS*** use `strlen`

3. `printf("%d", ...`  (both) invoke undefined behaviour as you use the wrong format. It has to be `%zu` for type `size_t`

This program demonstrated the difference between `strlen` and `sizeof`:

```
int main(void) {
    char strq[] = " world";
    char strp[1000] = "hello";

    strcat(strp,strq);
    puts(strp); //hello world
    printf("sizeof(strp) = %zu ",sizeof(strp));
    printf("strlen(strp) = %zu",strlen(strp));
    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
hello world
sizeof(strp) = 1000 strlen(strp) = 11
```